# erlang connecting to tinkerpop via REST

Tags: erlang, titan, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkergraph

1. In the Tinkerpop or Titan documentation, all operations are based on a sample graph. How to creat a new empty graph to work on?
2. I am programming in erlang connecting to Tinkergraph, planned to use Titan later in production. There is no erlang driver for both so I am connecting by REST. It is easy to read from graph, but if I want to read from user's input then write into the graph, for example, to create a person named teddy:

[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCE89.jpg)

I got those errors. What is the correct way?

Thank you.

Update: For following situation:

23> Newperson=terry.

terry

24> Newperson.

terry

If I want to add this terry, below two will not work. What's the correct way to do it?

[screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFspo.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

**1**

`TitanGraph titanGraph = TitanFactory.open(config);` will open a titan graph without the sample data.

If you have already commited the sample data to your keyspace then you can just change the keyspace defined in your `config` file.

For example if you are using a cassandra backend you would change `storage.cassandra.keyspace=xxxxxx` .

You can also clear any keyspace using `TitanCleanup.clear(graph);`

**2**

As for the error you are seeing. It looks like you are trying to label your vertex incorrectly. I posted the following and it worked:

```
{ 
    "gremlin" : "g.addV(label, x).property(y,z)",
    "bindings" : 
    {
        "x" : "person",
        "y" : "name",
        "z" : "Teddy"
    }
}
```

A final note, when you start using Titan 1.0.0 make sure you checkout [this](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0.M6/#_connecting_via_rest) section of the tinkerpop docs. Especially make sure to change the channel in the `gremlin-server.yaml` config to:

```
channelizer: com.tinkerpop.gremlin.server.channel.HttpChannelizer
```

Comment: Thank you Fido, by read your answer, I found why I was wrong, my bindings is not correct, I didn't put the value in quotation mark. It should be \"bindings\":\"NewName\":\"Teddy\". I put it as :teddy. Besides, g.addV('person').property('name','stephen') is also correct expression, checkout here: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/reference/#addvertex-step

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question: construct a Body by lists:concat() or ++, then post